# BCP export with a comma row delimiter

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I currently have a sproc that is exporting data to a csv file using bcp.  It currently works fine except due to a change of requirment the file no longer can have a '\n' row delimiter and must now have a ',' row delimiter.  From a quick search I found that the tag you need to add is '-r *delimiter*' however my export appears to now be in a different language encoding.

This is the logic I am using to build my execution query:

```
SET @tempSQL = 'bcp "select * from ' + @tempTableName + ' " queryout "' + @fileName +'" -T -c -t"," -r"," -k -CRAW'
```

**Additional Details:** When opening the file in Notepad++ or vim it looks fine however when viewed in notepad it looks like Chinese characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What encoding does Notepad think the file is? If I open an ASCII file wth Unicode selected for the encoding, that's what I see.

File -> Open, 'Encoding:' selector at the bottom of the dialog (on Win7)

Comment: You were on to something, it appeared to be an encoding issue.